# Difference Between PTAS and FPTAS

Tags: approximation, polynomial-time

According to this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polynomial-time-approximation-scheme/):

> Polynomial Time Approximation Scheme (PTAS) is a type of approximate
>   algorithms that provide user to control over accuracy which is a
>   desirable feature. These algorithms take an additional parameter ε > 0
>   and provide a solution that is (1 + ε) approximate for minimization
>   and (1 – ε) for maximization. For example consider a minimization
>   problem, if ε is 0.5, then the solution provided by the PTAS algorithm
>   is 1.5 approximate. The running time of PTAS must be polynomial in
>   terms of n, however, it can be exponential in terms of ε.
>
> In PTAS algorithms, the exponent of the polynomial can increase
>   dramatically as ε reduces, for example if the runtime is O(n(1/ε)!)
>   which is a problem. There is a stricter scheme, Fully Polynomial Time
>   Approximation Scheme (FPTAS). In FPTAS, algorithm need to polynomial
>   in both the problem size n and 1/ε.

What I dont understand is the second paragraph stated above. Can someone explain to me whats the difference between FPTAS from PTAS? Can you enlighten me about `exponent of the polynomial can increase dramatically as ε reduces` and `algorithm need to polynomial in both the problem size n and 1/ε.` ? I really dont get it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have an $\epsilon$-approximation algorithm $A$ which runs in $n^2+2^\frac1\epsilon$ on an instance of size $n$ and another one, $B$ which runs in $n^2+\frac1\epsilon$ (to give you an other example).

(I'm not using big-O notation to make it easier to talk about the polynomial bounds).

Now if you say $1/\epsilon$ is a constant, $2^\frac1\epsilon$ and $\frac1\epsilon$ both become constants, and you can say that the runtime of both $A$ and $B$ is bounded by a polynomial in $n$. Meaning that only $n$ is seen as a variable of that polynomial, as $\epsilon$ is a constant. So both $A$ and $B$ qualify as PTAS.

However, if this time you don't consider $1/\epsilon$ like a constant and want to include it as a variable in a polynomial upper bound, the situation changes.

- For $B$, there exists some polynomial $p(x,y)$ of two variables $x$ and $y$, such that the runtime of $B$ is at most $p(n,1/\epsilon)$ for all $n,\epsilon > 0$. For example, $p(x,y) = x^2 + y$ works, because $n^2+\frac1\epsilon \leq p(n,1/\epsilon)$. Thus $B$ qualifies as a FPTAS.
- For $A$ however, it is not possible to find such a polynomial. For every polynomial $p(x,y)$, you know that $n^2+2^\frac1\epsilon > p(n,1/\epsilon)$ once $1/\epsilon$ becomes big enough (or equivalently, once $\epsilon$ becomes small enough). Thus $A$ does not qualify as a FPTAS.